# How to change state inside nested object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i have parrent and child component. Parrent component is receiving data from server. This data are saved in state.data. Now, when i do action in child component, it should be call method from parrent controller. This is working now. Problem is inside this method which i am calling. I am receiving id as parameter. This data in parrent have list of items (packages) and every item has id. I need to update only one of them by id (or other way i don't know right way). Please how i can do it? I need to update isOpen state only that one item i open by  clicking on button in child component
My method (but i am not sure if i started to do this right way), i stucked on this problem for while:

```
changeIsOpenState(typeOfPart: Number, id: Number) {
        console.log(this.state.data.packages);
        const selectedObject = this.state.data.packages.filter((obj) => {
            const val= (obj.id === id) ? obj : false;
            return val;
        });
    }
```

Array of data i want update (isOpen property).

[image: data i need to change]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:
1.I copy current data to another variable
2.Filter data by id
3.Save array key of item with same id
4. Change cloned value with negation
5. save new data to state

```
 changeIsOpenState(typeOfPart: Number, id: Number) {
        const subjectDataCopy = cloneDeep(this.state.data);
        const keys = [];
        subjectDataCopy.packages.filter((obj, key) => {
            if (obj.id === id) {
                keys.push(key);
            }
        });
        subjectDataCopy.packages[keys[0]].isOpen = !subjectDataCopy.packages[keys[0]].isOpen;
        this.setState({data: subjectDataCopy});
    }
```

If there is better option to do this please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

what about immutably? I think u can use [dot-prop-immutable](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable) package in this way:

```js
const state = {
  packages: [
    { isOpen: false, id: 1 },
    { isOpen: false, id: 2 },
    { isOpen: false, id: 3 }
  ]
};
const index = state.packages.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 3);
const newState = dotProp.set(state, `packages[${index}].isOpen`, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it the ol' way :

```
changeIsOpenState(typeOfPart: Number, id: Number) {
  // Copy the packages so you won't mumtate your state directly
  const packages = Object.assign({}, ...this.StaticRange.data.packages);

  // Get the package to edit and its index in the packages object
  let packageIndex;
  let packageToEdit;

  for(let i = 0; i <= packages.length; i++){
    if(packages[i].id === id){
      packageIndex = i;
      packageToEdit = packages[i];
      packageToEdit.isOpen = true
    }
  }
  packages[packageIndex] = packageToEdit;
  setState({...this.state, data:{...this.state.data, packages}});
}
```